# Rails Admin filtering multiselect

Tags: rails-admin

I have a model with these associations:

```
  has_many :ad_places, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :places, through: :ad_places
```

And in my Rails Admin initializer:

```
  edit do
    field :places do
      inline_add false
      associated_collection_cache_all true
      associated_collection_scope do
        Proc.new do |scope|
          scope = scope.order(:place_on_page)
        end
      end
    end
    field :html, :text
    field :document
  end
```

But my entries on the multiselect are not ordered by `place_on_page`, the request that does Rails Admin is `ORER by places.id desc`

It's basically the same configuration than [this guy](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2231) that's been fixed by [this fix](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/2412) except that it doesn't work for me.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs on development to see what SQL is being generated, probably there's another ordering somewhere. to fix that try:

```
scope = scope.reorder(:place_on_page)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I looked at the logs and really the only two SQL requests made for places are `SELECT "places".* FROM "places" INNER JOIN "ad_places" ON "places"."id" = "ad_places"."place_id" WHERE "ad_places"."ad_id" = $1` and `SELECT "places".* FROM "places" ORDER BY places.id desc` even with your solution my order or reorder is not taken in account (sorry for the delay I was off until today)